# Jquery serialize() method is returning null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `serialize()` method in my JSP page. But its returning null. Dont know what I am doing wrong
Please help.

**jQuery Code :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#addBtn").click(function() {
      var offerData = $("#testForm").serialize();
      alert(offerData);
  }

});
```

**HTML Code :**

```
<form id="testForm">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Name :</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Address :</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="address" id="address" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <input type="button" id="addBtn" />
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

I posted relevant code only.

Comment: Closing bracket `alert(offerData); });`

Comment: Sane indentation would show the error almost immediately.

Comment: could you once replace input type button to submit and try. If not working then also then try using the form id selector and post the response :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your javascript code is bad formatted, I tried this and it works fine...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

      $("#addBtn").click(function () {
          var offerData = $("#testForm").serialize(); 
          alert(offerData);
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="testForm">
<table>
<tr>
 <td>Name :</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Address :</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="address" id="address"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<input type="button" id="addBtn"/>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in your javascript code. It should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {

      $("#addBtn").click(function () {
          var offerData = $("#testForm").serialize(); 
          alert(offerData);
          });
         });
</script>
```

Notice the closing bracket and semicolon after your `click` method.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot the close parenthesis, the code below works

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addBtn").click(function () {
      var offerData = $("#testForm").serialize(); 
      alert(offerData);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="testForm">
<table>
<tr>
 <td>Name :</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Address :</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="address" id="address"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<input type="button" id="addBtn"/>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing closing parenthesis for **click** event handler. Also in the **HTML** the last `<tr>` has no `<td>` included. Consider including your `input` element into `<td colspan="2">`

### jQuery

```
  $("#addBtn").click(function() {
      var offerData = $("#testForm").serialize();
      alert(offerData);
  }); // <-- missing );
```

### HTML

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">
    <input type="button" id="addBtn" />
  </td>
</tr>
```